# Write logic to wrap usage of Multer middlware (Express.js)

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, multer

I'm using the `multer` middlware to upload files like so:

```
import multer from 'multer';

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, callback) => {
    callback(null, './');
},
    filename: (req, file, callback) => {
    callback(null, `${Date.now()}${file.originalname}`);
}
});

const uploadFile = multer({ storage });

export default uploadFile.single('file');
```

And the route I'm using the middlware from:

```
router.post('/upload--file', uploadFile);
```

The issue is,  I want to to add some logic before saving the file,  after saving it etc.

How should I do it? I'm confused as I can't edit the middleware itself obviously.

Comment: https://github.com/expressjs/multer#error-handling is all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is for error handling on multer but should answer your question on how to **wrap the multer middleware to add your logic** before the multer upload.

[Link to solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71119502/i-dont-know-how-to-handle-errors-in-multer-with-express/71148498#71148498)